# Can I compare the contents of two databases in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: sql, azure-data-studio, data-comparison

I have two databases and I want to do a data comparison between the two. In SSDT this can easily be achieved using the Data Compare feature, but I'm trying to move to using Azure Data Studio. I can see there's a schema comparison extension in Data Studio, but struggling to find a data comparison - does it exist?

Comment: I cannot find one either. There is an extension that will purportedly move a table from one server to another --> eltsnap: Simple Dataflow. Then you could just use SQL to compare. I prefer RStudio to compare the data.

Comment: it's too late to add a comment but I just found a link today as I had the same requirement, it provided a few tools but most of them are commercial except two.
https://dbmstools.com/categories/data-compare-tools/azure-sql-database